Flask application wtforms activate select2
I'm trying to activate select2 on my Flask app on wtforms form. I have and nothing happened, selectfield still not searchable.
I tried to go step with step by documentation and nothing happened... filed still not searchable.
I added the cdn under head section:
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>

I have ccity parameter on server.py file:

ccity = SelectField('עיר לקוח', choices=dropdown_list, default=1)

Then on HTML added the script section related to my ccity:
    <div class = "container" dir="rtl">
        <h4>הוספת לקוח</h4>
        <br>
        {% from "_formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
        <form method=post action="/addcustomer/">
            <dl>
                {{render_field(form.cname)}}
                {{render_field(form.ccity)}}
                {{render_field(form.caddress)}}
                {{render_field(form.clicense)}}
            </dl>
            <p><input type=submit value=הוסף></p>
        </form>



    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#ccity').select2();
});

still look without search and nothing happens same as before please help.
enter image description here
